# Determining the component to use to display the values in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have below data to be rendered in the page using HTML5.

```
Score: 10

Has Account: Y/N (drop down)

Has House: Y/N (drop down)

Has Phone: Y/N (drop down)
```

Now could you please tell which HTML container to use to contain all above elements ? All label names should be in bold.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use div or table

Comment: ... or anything you want. Learn HTML, then come back if you have any particular problem.

Comment: This question can be answered in so many ways...

Comment: This can be done in any number of ways. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/BCt6z/

Comment: Bold or not has nothing to do with the container. And yes/no is usually done with checkboxes; radio buttons are also OK, but dropdowns are really frowned upon.